# Python script not running from apache when call it from PHP

Tags: php, python, apache

I have a python script which is used to remove noise from background of image. When I am calling this script from terminal it is working fine without any error. I am calling that script as below from terminal:

```
/usr/bin/python noise.py 1.png 100
```

But When I tried to calling it from PHP using apache it is giving me below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "./noise.py", line 2, in from PIL import Image, ImageFilter ImportError: No module named PIL
```

Can someone help me in resolving this issue? I tried to give permission to www-data user to that script, like this:

```
sudo chown www-data:www-data noise.py
```

But it doesn't help. Please help me.

Comment: Can you show us how do u call the Python script from php

Comment: @fortune: I am calling python script from PHP as below: /usr/bin/python ./noise.py 1.png 100  2>&1

Answer (score 0):

Do

chmod +x  noise.py

And call the Python script using full path like

system('/usr/bin/python SCRIPTFULLPATH/noise.py 1.png 100 2>&1' ,$op);

Comment: I am still getting this error: Traceback (most recent call last): File "SCRIPTFULLPATH/noise.py", line 2, in from PIL import Image, ImageFilter ImportError: No module named PIL

Comment: I think Apache uses different version of python installed on server. How can I check this if both terminal and apache uses same python

Comment: Script full path means your Python script full path i don't know where it is saved. If it's in /var/www/html, you have to provide/var/www/html/noise.py

Comment: Yes I did the same, I replaced SCRIPTFULLPATH with full path of python script.

Comment: Also you need to provide the png image full path

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this

```
sudo chown www-data:www-data noise.py

sudo chmod ugo+xrw noise.py

sudo pip install --upgrade pip

sudo service apache2 restart
```

Then after try refreshing again